# How install theme bought in themeforest in wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress

This is my domain information [link](http://who.is/whois/kennethquillinan.com) under [wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com). 
i can't upload my custom theme.
i want to upload a theme form the themeforest How to upload my costume theme ??

Answer (score 0):

install wordpress,you may check it here https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress-installation.htm

just follow the instructions.
then go to appearance>Themes> then add/uplaod the theme you bought then activate.
:)

Comment: I am not finding add new theme options because my site has under [link](http://wordpress.com) Please see this screenshot  [link](http://prntscr.com/as0z1g)

Comment: i think that is not a WordPress installer in your directory i think that is just a preview or an online building site, not sure. sorry bro..
do you have access to your directory? if yes download Wordpress, copy it your directory, then install it.

Comment: @SumonHasan did you fix it?